# Add featureset in graphics layer without iterating

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, geometry, graphics

I have a geoprocessing service that returns a large amount of features (featureSet). I want to attach them in a graphics layer, but I don't want to iterate over all them. I tried using the mygraphicLayer.graphics option so as to set the features (array of graphics) to the graphic layer but it does not work.

Have you got any idea how I could do this?

```
 function addCityFeatureSetToMap(featureSet) {
    console.debug("featureSet    ", featureSet)
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0,0,255]));

    //Create graphics layer for cities
    var cityLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer({
        graphics: featureSet.features
    });
    map.addLayer(cityLayer);
```

Comment: How many features? Is the reason you don't want to iterate because of the number of features?

Comment: Yes @ChadCooper It could be one reason. I don't like the idea of iteration, considering the the features of a feature Set is an array of Graphics[]. An Graphics layer constructor has an attribute Graphics[], which I suppose can be set immediately.

Answer (score 2):

edit:
i did a bit of fiddling and realized that my original answer is incorrect.  you need to loop through individual graphics and [add()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#add) them one at a time because the [graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#graphics) property of GraphicsLayer is not 'settable'.

that being said, its important to note that there would be no performance benefit of the API exposing a technique to loading graphics in bulk because we would still need to loop through individual geometries internally to insert them into the DOM.

original answer:
i'm not sure you're going to see a performance gain in taking this approach, but it should work just fine as long as you set an appropriate [renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#renderer) for the GraphicsLayer.

```
var myRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(symbol);
cityLayer.renderer = myRenderer;
cityLayer.graphics = featureSet.features;
cityLayer.redraw();
```

right now you're passing an array of [graphic](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html) objects with no symbol defined whatsoever.

Comment: Thans for your answer @John Gravois. However i have already set a renderer later in my code. I will correct it in my question so as to be clear

Answer (score 0):

I would extend the GraphicsLayer this way

```
GraphicsLayer.prototype.addGraphics = function(arrayOfGraphics){
  var that = this;
  arrayUtil.forEach(arrayOfGraphics, function(graphic){
   that.add(graphic);
  });
}
```